# ISAPI Rewrite - ReverseProxy doesn't handle images

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I'm using ISAPI Rewrite 3 under ASP.NET / IIS 7.

My `.htaccess` file is pretty short:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteProxy ^(forum|events|support|_css|css|_js)(.*) http://othersite/$1$2
```

Requests like `http://mysite/events/page1.aspx`, or `http://mysite.com/css/site.css`, everything works great. However, requests for images `http://mysite/images/smurf.gif` are apparently not processed by ISAPI Rewrite, and I receive a 404 error.

The error page also references a weird url. For instance, if I request `/images/smurf.png`, the error page will show `/images/smurf.png.rwhp`. I think `.rwhp` stands for "RewriteHelper", and seems to be coming from ISAPI Rewrite itself. This suggests that the handler *is* processing the request, but is doing something very strange with it.

How can I get around this? Why is this only happening for images?

Comment: For URL-Rewriting, why not use asp.net's url rewrite (Routing) feature?

Comment: Legacy. We've got around 600+ rules already in .htaccess, and quite a bit of stuff still running on IIS6/Win2k3. Converting them all to use app routing/IIS url rewriting will be a significant pain.

Comment: But, if you think about the exponentially growing system of coding - you need to figure out constants. URL rewriting in .Net is one of those constants developed by Microsoft and used everywhere :)

Comment: There are a lot of things I'd like to rewrite. In high-traffic, mission-critical systems, though, it's rarely as simple as it seems.

Comment: It may happen if /images is not an ordinary folder and ISAPI_Rewrite handler is removed for it.

Comment: @TonyCool since it's a reverse proxy rule instead of a rewrite (in fact, the folder is on a completely different server), then it shouldn't matter if ISAPI Rewrite is running there or not. My understanding is that basically issues a second request (browser -> server A -> proxy to server B) so whatever systems are in place there should still be working. Browser requests for the image directly form the second server work just fine.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you create a ticket on HeliconTech helpdesk (support@helicontech.com). Please enable logging in httpd.conf and attach the rewrite.log for the non-working request.